# WCF Service с BasicHttpBinding плюс аутентификация по имени пользователя и паролю

Tags: c#, wcf

Всем привет. Используя в качества руководства [статью](http://www.brhlavinka.com/2013/06/07/secure-wcf-service-with-basichttpbinding-and-custom-credentials/) пытаюсь реализовать аутентификацию для `WCF` сервиса. При запуске приложения в Visual Studio 2015 получаю исключение: `"Для конечной точки с привязкой BasicHttpBinding не удалось найти базовый адрес, соответствующий схеме https. Зарегистрированные схемы базовых адресов — [http]."` Побороть данную проблему не получилось. Прошу помощи.

Контракт:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Brett.Service
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
}
```

Сервис:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Brett.Service
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} entered: {1}", GetCurrentUserName(), value);
        }

        private string GetCurrentUserName()
        {
            var primaryIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;

            if (primaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return primaryIdentity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(@"User is not authenticated...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Валидатор:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Brett.Service
{
    public class CustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != @"hello")
            {
                throw new FaultException(@"User name must be 'hello'.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Конфиг:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Brett.Service.Service1"
           behaviorConfiguration="Brett_Behavior">
        <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Brett_BindingConfiguration"
              contract="Brett.Service.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Brett_BindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Brett_Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Brett.Service.CustomValidator, Brett.Service"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Вы бы привели немного кода.

Comment: @VladD, добавил код.

Comment: покажите код публикации сервиса. где вы его публикуете? В IIS? Это ошибка возникает, когда вы публикуете сервис на http адресе, хотя здесь он ожидает публикацию на защищенном http(https)

Comment: Под кодом публикации Вы имеете ввиду файл с расширением `.pubxml`?

Comment: не совсем, ваш сервис где опубликован? в IIS, либо вы сами его публикуете через ServiceHost? Если вы делали вcе по статье, то получается в IIS. Поэтому вопрос, вы выполнили настройку публикации сервиса в IIS? Добавили https-привязку с привязкой к этой точке SSL-сертификата? Почему то мне кажется, что вы этого не сделали. И причина должна быть в этом.

Comment: Да, сервис будет развернут в IIS, но его настройкой я еще толком не занимался. Т.к. хотел заставить все это дело сначала работать по студией, или это (работать под студией) сделать ни как?

Comment: сделать можно, через app.config также можно сделать привязку сертификата. Поэтому я и интересуюсь у вас, где вы будете публиковать сервис? Если в IIS, то в той статье уже все описано. Если через Studio, то тогда необходимо еще доработать ваш файл конфигурации с публикацией сервиса. То есть ваш текущий результат такой - вы сделали НЕ ВСЕ, что написано в статье. А только половину.

Comment: А что необходимо сделать, что бы все это дело запустилось сначала под студией, каким образом поправить конфиг?

Comment: На IIS все развернул и заработало. Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь подскажет как запустить под Visual Studio.